# Grouping the name in the manner of years and months from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, collections

i had created a class with two properties one of `datetime` datatype and other of string.

```
public class name1
{
public DateTime dob { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and then page load created a list

```
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1989, 5, 12);
    DateTime d2 = new DateTime(1989, 5, 26);
    DateTime d3 = new DateTime(1989, 3, 12);
    DateTime d4 = new DateTime(1986, 3, 21);
    DateTime d5 = new DateTime(1990, 8, 19);

    List<name1> randmoptn=new List<name1>();
    name1 n1=new name1();
    n1.name="rachit";
    n1.dob=d1;
    name1 n2=new name1();
    n2.name="abhinav";
    n2.dob=d2;
    name1 n3=new name1();
    n3.name="mandeep";
    n3.dob=d3;
    name1 n4=new name1();
    n4.name="jasmeet";
    n4.dob=d4;
    name1 n5=new name1();
    n5.name="rajat";
    n5.dob=d5;
    randmoptn.Add(n1);
    randmoptn.Add(n2);
    randmoptn.Add(n3);
    randmoptn.Add(n4);
    randmoptn.Add(n5);
```

and now i wanted 
**desired output should be**

`year 1986`

`month 3`

`21/3/1986    jasmeet`

`year 1989`

`month 3`

`12/3/1989   mandeep`

`month 5`
`12/5/1989  rachit`

`26/5/1989  abhinav`

`year 1990`

`month 8`

`19/8/1990  rajat`

Comment: Do you want to PRINT the outputs in the screen?

Comment: There are lots, of ways of doing, that Linq, Tuple, a Sort, write a NameDOBCollection class... What have you tried. Waht else do you need from it. Do you need the Name1 class, will you want other stuff like by Alpha ordered names. Too ambiguous a question for me.

Comment: i want to do it without linq.

Comment: +1 to the "too ambiguous" comment but basically you need to implement IComparable for your class to sort by the birthdate property, sort your List, then loop through and print the values you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired output is as below

- Year
- Month
- DoB with Name

then do something like this

```
foreach item in YourList  
{  
   print item.dob.year; // this will return year in integer format
   print item.dob.month; // this will return month in integer format
   print item.dob; // this will return DoB as dateformat, do whatever formating you want 
   print item.name; // this will return Name as String  
}
```

print the DoB and Name in the same line if you want

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have completed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var q=from x in randmoptn
            group x by new { Year=x.dob.Year,Month=x.dob.Month} into month 
            group month by month.Key.Year into year
            select new { Year=year.Key,Months=year.OrderBy (y =>y.Key.Month )};

    foreach (var year in q) {
        Console.WriteLine("year {0}",year.Year);
        foreach (var month in year.Months) {
            Console.WriteLine("month {0}",month.Key.Month);
            foreach (var item in month) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy},{1}",item.dob,item.name);
            }

        }
    }
```